# ngRoute does not work

Tags: angularjs, resolve, ngroute

I have two problems with angular routing and resolve. I am very new on Angularjs. Thats why my questions could be very stupid.

1. When I enter `mysite/lsrc?q=keyword` on the address bar of browser, browser shows the Json result on the page. Browser could not be forwarded to `searchView.html`.

   But I have an event on pageCtrl.js. Page could be forwarded to the same URL by `$location.path('/lsrc').search(searchService);` You can also see the mentioned event below.
2. I could not see the searcView model on the searchView.html. I think my

Here's the related code parts

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/lsrc', {
        templateUrl: '/app/search/searchView.html',
        controller: 'SearchController as vMain',
        //resolve:
        resolve: {
            searchResource: "searchResource",
            searchService: "searchService",
            searchView: function (searchResource, searchService) {
                return searchResource.query(searchService).$promise;
            }
        }
    });
```

**PageControl.js:**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("logicApp")
        .controller("PageController", ['searchService', '$location',
    PageController]);

    function PageController(searchService, $location) {
        var vmPage = this;
        //forward page to the searc view
        vmPage.LogicSearch = function ($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            $location.path('/lsrc').search(searchService);
        };
    }
})();
```

**SearchController.js:**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("logicApp")
        .controller("SearchController", ['searchView', SearchController]);
    function SearchController(searchView) {
        var vMain = this;
        vMain.searchView = searchView;
    }
})();
```

**SearchView.html:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in vMain.searchView.Items">
    <li class="product-little-pic">{{item.ImageUrl}}</li>
</ul>
```

**searchResource.js:**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("logicApp")
        .factory("searchResource", ["$resource", searchResource]);
    // enter code here
    function searchResource($resource) {
        return $resource("/lsrc");
    }
})();
```

Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It seems you have a typo in `templateUrl: '/app/search/SearchView.html'`. `SearchView.html` starts with a capital letter but in your text you say `searchView.html`. Try to use lowercase.

Comment: Hi @maxdec, thanks for your comment. It is correct on the development enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

My second problem was solved. I have changed the SearchController as below.
It seems after promise I missed the call back function.

```
function SearchController(searchView) {
        var vMain = this;
        vMain.searchView = searchView.$promise.then(function (result) {
            vMain.searchView = result[0];
        });
    }
```